# Open gl draw turns white after one frame drawn

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am newbie in Opengl. I used the following example from Qt as a start in Opengl as I know Qt.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-squircle-cpp.html

I replaced the paint function of the program with following code with an intent to draw chess board pattern. Following is not the paint or render function of my program

```
paint()
{
if (!m_program) {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
                                       "attribute highp vec4 vertices;"
                                       "varying highp vec2 coords;"
                                       "void main() {"
                                       "    gl_Position = vertices;"
                                       "    coords = vertices.xy;"
                                       "}");
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
                                       "uniform lowp float t;"
                                       "varying highp vec2 coords;"
                                       "void main() {"
                                       "    lowp float i = 1. - (pow(abs(coords.x), 4.) + pow(abs(coords.y), 4.));"
                                       "    i = smoothstep(t - 0.8, t + 0.8, i);"
                                       "    i = floor(i * 20.) / 20.;"
                                       "    gl_FragColor = vec4(coords * .5 + .5, i, i);"
                                       "}");

    m_program->bindAttributeLocation("vertices", 0);
    m_program->link();
}

auto width = static_cast<float>(m_viewportSize.width());
auto height = static_cast<float>(m_viewportSize.height());
auto a = 2.f / width;
auto b = 2.f / height;
std::vector<float> matrix =
{
     a , 0, 0, 0,
     0, -b, 0, 0,
     0,  0, 1, 0,
    -1,  1, 0, 1
};

// Set the projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(matrix.data());

// Initialize vertices:
std::vector<float> vertices =
{
    0,     0,
    0,     height,
    width, height,
    width, 0
};

// Initialize colors
std::vector<float> colors =
{
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 1
};

// Initialize texture virtice
std::vector<float> texCoord =
{
    0, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
    1, 0
};

// Create texture: simple chess board 8x8
auto numRows = 8u;
auto numCols = 8u;
auto character = 172u;
auto remain = 255u - character;
std::vector<unsigned char> texture(numCols * numRows);
for (auto i = 0u; i < texture.size(); ++i)
    texture[i] = ((i + (i / numCols)) % 2) * remain + character;

// Upload to GPU texture
unsigned textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, numCols, numRows, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.data());

// Initialize clear colors
glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
// Activate necessary states
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.data());
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors.data());
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoord.data());

// render
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

m_program->disableAttributeArray(0);
m_program->release();
m_window->resetOpenGLState();
}
```

The chess board is drawn. But its drawn for a split second & then the screen turns fully white. I want to draw the chess board pattern continiously with each frame draw. 
Can someone pls point out what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Yes, looking at your last 5 lines you're drawing a single frame, then you begin releasing the GL program and reset the window.

Comment: I commented out the last 3 lines but it does not help.

Comment: Why is my question down voted ? whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Is the vote count important for your question?

Comment: @Mio Bambino yes. I think so. after getting these down votes, after a while I might not be able to post any other question. as I learnt from stacoverflow rules. But I want to understand the reason of down voting. if there is a mistake, then I would like to not repeat it next time while posting questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top you have:

```
if (!m_program) {
```

then you initialize `m_program`, at the very bottom you have:

```
m_program->release();
```

which as Harish in comments points out is equivalent to calling `glUseProgram(0);`. So in the next iteration of `paint` your shader is not bound and not available.

According to docs, the reverse of `release();` is `bind();` so (I am not expert on this class) the solution might be to call `QOpenGLShaderProgram::bind()` on the next iteration of your `paint`.

Comment: `m_program->release()` is the same as `glUseProgram(0)`. It may cause memory leak in his code, but is not why he is getting a white screen. See link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshaderprogram.html#release

Comment: @Harish see now if my answer is more usefull

Comment: calling bind displays the data continuously every frame now. I also commented out the call to addShaderFromSourceCode. As I told I am a newbie in open gl, I copied the sample & from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-squircle-cpp.html       . My target to provide my own char data from an image that I have & replaced the chess board pattern with an actual image data (unsigned char array) that I have. Please comment if I am on the right. This discussion has been certainly helpful for me  guys

Comment: The answer looks more appropriate  now. @Nelson P accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it's a good idea to run opengl programs through a graphics debugger like gDEbugger to give you an insight into what's actually happening inside the API.

Comment: Good point @The Sombero Kid. I will try getting the gDebbugger on. At the moment I am mostly sort of wondering happening behind the API